# Laravel Broadcast Private Channel doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher

I'm trying to do some real-time push notifications using *Laravel WebSockets* as a **socket server** and *Laravel Echo* with `Events`.

When I'm doing it on `Channel`, it is working fine, but now I want it to send it to *private channel*.

```
Channel('reservation.' . $this->random_key);
```

to

```
PrivateChannel('reservation.' . $this->random_key);
```

#### `NewReservationEvent.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewReservationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $random_key;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message, $user)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->random_key = $user->random_key;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('reservation.' . $this->random_key);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'reservation.event';
    }
}
```

#### `routes/channels.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/

Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('reservation.{random_key}', function ($user, $random_key){
    return true;
});
```

#### `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/sendEvent', function () {
    $superAdmins = User::where('role', 'Super')->get();

    foreach ($superAdmins as $superAdmin) {
        $message = 'Reservation added by';
        event(new NewReservationEvent($message, $superAdmin));
    }
});
```

#### `BroadcastServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth', 'checkRole:Super,Admin,Customer']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

And here is the `Echo` on my view:

```
Echo.private('reservation.{{ auth()->user()->random_key }}')
    .listen('.reservation.event', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message);

        $("#refreshThisDropdown").load(window.location.href + " #refreshThisDropdown");
        $("#refreshThisDropdown").load(" #refreshThisDropdown > *");

        toastr.success(e.message, "Hello there");
    })
```

It all works fine on *Channel* mode, I want to make it **private** just for more security.

Comment: your in sesssion base auth to token based auth ?

Comment: ya, I protect it with auth. and create check role middleware to access some routes

Comment: i posted my answer can you check if you set this then `/auth` api will automatically hit to authorize websocket private channel

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue i solved this by adding `Gurad` in `Channel.php`

like this

#### `routes/channels.php`

```php
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
}, ['guards' => ['web', 'auth']]);

Broadcast::channel('reservation.{random_key}', function ($user, $random_key){
    return true;
}, ['guards' => ['web', 'auth']]);
```

Comment: i try this but sadly, it doesnt work. i have github repo for this if you want to see my full code.
and i got other clue at my /larave-websockets.
whenever i put the channel to privatechannel, it doesnt subscribe, it just show connection 799386905.254837412 Origin: http://127.0.0.1. is it normal?

Comment: to subscribe private channel laravel need authorization which laravel automatic call a api there your getting isse

Comment: i think im getting closer to solve, so ive change 
Broadcast::channel('reservation.{random_key}', function ($user, $random_key){
    return true;
}, ['middleware' => ['auth', 'checkRole:Super,Admin,Customer']]);
and this public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }

Comment: and my private channel now subscribed at events, but now i got an error on console app.js:21789 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden). but if i add middleware auth check role at broadcast routes, my private channel just cannot subscribe anymore.

Comment: then you need to play with `guards`  add right `guards` then it will connnet otherwise you will get `403`